# css need to work without the font css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

- i have a codepen where the react functionality works fine...
- but when I transfer into another codepen with same code its not working...due to the below link tag...

- can you guys tell me how to make the current code working without this link tag...with a normal css
- providing my code below..

working code

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbgxdb**

not working code
**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwBeWZ**

```
.fa-search {
    color: #2980b9;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .fa-times-circle {
    opacity: 0;
    color: #d9d9d9;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    right: 8px;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .search-input {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: default;
    left: 45px;
    top: 6px;
    width: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    transition: width 0.4s ease-out;
  }
```

Comment: Dear you need to be more clear :)

Comment: @kanudo if you see it in the settings tab of html in head section... you will come to know...i tried my best ways to explain

Comment: Font-awesome provides you with the search icon in a `:before` when you remove font-awesome, that icon isn't there. The `:before` provided your `span` with some dimensions so you can click on it. So either provide a `:before` or add some `width` and `height` to your span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just improve the css and it will work even without the font awesome link.

```
.fa-search {
color: #2980b9;
font-size: 30px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
cursor: pointer;
/* ------------------------- just add the css below */
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Here is the working **[PEN](http://codepen.io/Bhavyesh/pen/MKLQmM)**

You can also specify exact pixel value as

```
height: 46px;
width:  46px;
```

as you outer div is with 50px height and 50px width with 2px border equals 46px height and 46px width as it has inherited `box-sizing: border-box;`